# Blind Dates Not As Person to Person but As People to People

Tags: word-choice

Here in Asia there's some peculiar cultural concept especially for early 20's so called 'meeting'(literally called in this way) which is a basically concept of blind dates but not by person to person but by people to people, usually 3 males to 3 females or 4 males to 4 females (very rarely in 2 by 2)

Is there any suggestive English word which mostly well fit to the above cultural collective behavior?

The main purpose of this so called 'meeting' could be diverse, such as seeking for potential date-mates or girl&boyfriends, but basically it's a gathering seeking for the any kind of fun something from the other gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's simply called [group dating](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_dating).

Comment: According to the explanations on wiki, it sounds perfectly fit to what I had explained in OP. Thx

Comment: @Daschin no problem ^^